# 500 internal server error checklist, curl request via internal ip (linux to windows IIS 7.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, curl

I have a simple post page in c#

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="post.aspx.cs" Inherits="PostReceiver.post" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="post.aspx" >
     <asp:HiddenField ID="order_id" runat="server"  />
     <asp:HiddenField ID="name" runat="server" Value="" />
     <asp:HiddenField ID="password" runat="server" Value="" />
<asp:Button ID="button2" Runat="server" Text="submit" PostBackUrl="~/post.aspx" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the back end C# is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string orderId = "";
        var coinName = "";
        var password = "";

        foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
        {
            if (key == "order_id")
            {
                orderId = key;
            }
            if (key == "name")
            {
                coinName = key;
            }
            if (key == "password")
            {
                password = key;
            }

        }

        if (orderId != "" && coinName != "" && password != "")
        {
            if (password == "password")
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Queue\\" + coinName + ".txt", true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("coinName");
                };
            }

        }

    }
```

that I have installed and tested on a live server.  I can make post requests to it directly from my linux server using

`curl --data "order_id=5&name=Hrenk&password=password" http://donate.ppcointalk.org/post.aspx`

So I know the post page works, yet when I try post internally

```
curl --data "order_id=5&name=Hrenk&password=password" http://192.168.135.192/post.aspx
```

I get 500 Internal server errors.

Googling 500 errors... I have checked the following:

- .NET 4.5 installed (even put on MVC 3 for good measure)
- Application pool set to .net framework 4.030319
- Set IIS bindings on my windows server to 192.168.135.192 port 80 for my post page website
- Set permissions to full access on the directory c:/Queue

Anyone any suggestions what else to try? or how to get more information out? do i need to specify a port for an internal network post? or default 80 in the bindings ok? should I be sending this https?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really need a web site .aspx? Why not use a service or web api http://www.asp.net/web-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found through accessing the windows server I could try the request on the browse in IIS on the sidebar.
This gave me a 500.21 error and that I tried re-registering .net 4

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_reglis.exe -i
```